# MAC Hard Drive in Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, mac

How to mount a MAC OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) Hard Drive in Ubuntu?
I use this HD as Time machine for my mac book backup, also I have some other files in it.
But when I connected to my Dell laptop both of Ubuntu and W7 does not mount it :(

I also install hfs explorer, but it did not help!

Comment: Already answered at SuperUser:

http://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write